# 7zip client: Compress dirs with method PPMd & compression level Ultra

Tags: compression, 7z

So today, I am trying to compress multiple folders, of old photos which I want to backup.

I've found this [article](https://www.riksoft.it/wikiriks/software/7zip-maximum-compression-settings-for-images), that says method PPMd, and compression level Ultra, are far better for image compression.

The command I'm executing is:
`7z a ./output.7z /path/to/dir1/ /path/to/dir2/ -m=PPMd -mx=9`

And the output has an error `E_INVALIDARG`:

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz (306D4),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive:
2 folders, 318 files, 1421027053 bytes (1356 MiB)

Creating archive: ./output.7z

Items to compress: 320



System ERROR:
E_INVALIDARG
```

The thing I don't understand is, since the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z), has the `-m | METHOD` parameter, and the `-mx | Compression Level` parameter, it stills throws an error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
Damian G.

*** Note: My OS is Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64***
*** Bash Version is 5.0.3(1)-release ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct use is

```
7z a ./output.7z /path/to/dir1/ /path/to/dir2/ -m0=PPMd -mx=9
```

Source: (Search for PPMd)
https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

Comment: well, it works finally, thanks!